# Self Register doesn't work in wso2is 5.11.0 after self-signed certificate setup

Tags: wso2-identity-server

In wso2is 5.11.0 user trying to self register cause a "javax.net.ssl.SSLException: hostname in certificate didn't match:  != ........." exception. The same configuration with same keystore and trust-store works fine if backported to 5.10.0.

Thanks
Francesco

Answer (score 1):

In WSO2 IS-5.11, the server hostname for internal API calls is by default configured as `localhost`. This configuration is utilized to build the internal absolute URL of a service endpoint, which will be consumed at places that will generate internal API calls.
If you are configuring the hostname for evaluations (when there is no load balancer or proxy) you can follow this.

- Add 'localhost' as SAN for the certificate (**-ext SAN=dns:localhost**)

Here is a sample keystore generation:

```
keytool -genkey -alias newcert -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -keystore newkeystore.jks -dname "CN=wso2is.local, OU=Is,O=Wso2,L=SL,S=WS,C=LK" -storepass mypassword -keypass mypassword -ext SAN=dns:localhost
```

Also, if you are using single-node deployment(there is no load balancer or proxy) instead of adding SAN, defining `internal_hostname` value as the same as `hostname` value will resolve this issue

```
[server]
hostname = "is.dev.wso2.com"
internal_hostname = "is.dev.wso2.com"
```

Comment: Thank you so much; it works like a charm.